References for this generalisation of the Hubbard Stratonovich transformation?
The Hubbard Stratonovich transformation is a name for the following Gaussian integration identity
\begin{align}
e^{-\frac{1}{2}ax^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi a}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}v~ e^{-\frac{v^2}{2a} - ixv}.
\end{align}
It is used in some areas of physics, such as QFT, to simplify some integrals by swapping the $x^2$ (left hand side) in the exponent with a term linear in $x$, at the cost of introducing the Gaussian integral over $y$ (right hand side). I came across the following similar identity
\begin{align}
e^{-xy} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}u~\mathrm{d}v~ e^{ - u^2 - v^2 + x(u + iv) - y(u - iv)},
\end{align}
which is similar in that it linearises the $xy$ term in the exponent on the left hand side, at the cost of introducting integrals over $u$ and $v$.
By applying the second identity twice, you can derive the following interesting identity
\begin{align}
e^{-x^3} = \frac{1}{\pi^2}\int \mathrm{d}^2u~\mathrm{d}^2v~\exp\Big(-|u|^2 - |v|^2 + x\left[u + \overline u v - \overline v\right]\Big)
\end{align}
where $u$ and $v$ are complex numbers, $\mathrm{d}^2u = \mathrm{d}\Re{u}~\mathrm{d}\Im{u}$ and similarly for $\mathrm{d}v$, all integrals are from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, and an overline denotes the complex conjugate. Similar identities can be derived for $e^{-x^4}$, $e^{-x^5}$ etc.
My question is, are identities of this type used in similar contexts to the Hubbard stratonovich transformation? And if they are, could anyone provide a reference?
